# Screen resolution reverted to 800x600 after first software update on Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, display, display-resolution

I have just installed Lubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on my 9-yearold Acer Aspire 5630 laptop with Intel graphics.Screen resolution 1280x1024 was OK with Live CD and on installed OS until first Software Update this morning (15 April '19).If I issue xrandr command from terminal the correct resolution is shown at the top of the list and is shown as being selected. I can restore correct resolution with xrandr -c 0. I didn't use any updates during installation.
I have repeated installation with similar results.